# Is there any way to simplify these two subqueries into one?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the call

```
SELECT *,
    (SELECT first_name||' '||last_name FROM users WHERE user_id=U.invited_by) AS inviter,
    (SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE user_id=U.invited_by) AS inviter_first
    FROM users AS U
```

and that works.  But as you can see, the two subqueries are both retrieving pretty data from the same row.  Is there any way to simplify the two SELECT calls as one and still get the same results?

Comment: This link should also be helpful : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

Answer (score 4):

You have to do a join.  Since you are joining back to the same table use an alias.

```
SELECT U.*,
       i_table.first_name||' '||i_table.last_name AS inviter,
       i_table.first_name as inviter_first
FROM users as U
LEFT JOIN users as i_table on i_table.user_id=U.invited_by
```

Note this query changes your query from performing 2 queries per row (so 2n * n or O(n^2)) to performing 1 joined query.

If you have an index on user_id you should see amazing increases in performance.

If you don't it should still be a lot faster at O(2n)

Comment: These subqueries are the equivalent of an outer join.

Comment: "Scalar Correlated Subqueries" like the ones in the OP are always the same as an Outer Join, if there's no user with that `user_id` a `NULL` will be returned instead. So you need to switch to a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @dnoeth - I can make it a left join, I still think a inner join is probably what the OP wants.  But they can figure that out themselves.

Comment: I don't think `invited_by` is mandatory; what about the very first user?

Comment: Ok how about a list of users and who invited then for awarding referral bonuses.  I think this is a more common business case than one where you need to know who referee and are interested in cases where there is no inviter. But the OP knows for sure.

Comment: For the sake of the conversation, in my particular database, everyone except user index 0 has a invited_by user.  I'm not super concerned with performance as there will only be a few dozen users in the database... but it's good to know for future reference.